# org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert

Tags: publishing, 2011-sp1

Blow error is occurred when I publish Design Master Page for most of the publication however this is working in some publication.
version=Sdl Tridion 2011 sp1 -2

Committing Deployment Failed
Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-676091-66560, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-676091-66560, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta]

Comment: When was the last time you've run database maintenance on the Broker? Also, is this on an Oracle or SQL Server DB?

Comment: You could try to install hotfix [CM_2011.1.2.85339](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/CD_2011.1.2.85556_tcm89-21115.zip). (Login required).

Comment: We are using sql server database.As this development environment there is no database maintenance activity on broker.

Comment: I have tried hotfix but it is not solving the issue.